# What to do when I see a user not accepting answers?

Tags: discussion

Lately, [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/153260/technikfe) user has been asking a lot of questions, from which many have been downvoted and done have been deleted. This user has 18 questions, from which only 2 don't have an answer, but only a few have an accepted answer.

Example if an unaccepted answer: [Is there a solid block that doesn't suffocate entities in direwolf20 1.7.10?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/283045/is-there-a-solid-block-that-doesnt-suffocate-entities-in-direwolf20-1-7-10)

Should I do something when I find such users? Is not accepting answers to my questions bad (against the rules)?

Comment: It's poor form, but not "against the rules".

Comment: The only thing you can really do is upvote any good answers on his questions. We can't force a checkmark, and some sort of punishment for not clicking on a checkmark on an answer that may or may not have helped him seems quite extreme.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A user isn't under any requirement to accept answers to their questions, although it's certainly encouraged that they do. A quick look through that users posts shows that they do know how to accept answers, and just don't do so very often. As such, in this case, my suggestion would to **do nothing at all.**

If the user had no accepted answers, though, or was really new to the site, then giving them a helpful nudge can be a good idea, just make sure to be nice when you do say. Aka if they make a comment like "Thanks!", feel free to post a helpful comment like:

> If this post solved your problem, then feel free to click that checkmark to the left of the answer. That will let others know that your problem was solved, which makes it easier for future visitors with the same problem to find a solution.

Comment: That said, if you spam that comment across multiple answers, it is very annoying and feels like rep begging.

Comment: @Frank so we should only do it for certain answers?

Comment: @Alex Only do it for newer users, and don't do it frequently. If you go around posting it on every answer then you're posting it way too much.

Comment: @Wipqozn will that give someone a comment ban?

Comment: No it will unlikely result in a comment ban. It just won't be helpful.